# Why do lumps of sugar break more easily when blowing in it?

Tags: everyday-life, crystals

My question is simple, when you have a small lump of sugar, it's hard to break it with your bare hands, but when you blow in it, it appears to be more easy. (it's a piece of advice i learned for my gran, and it works !)

Is it due to humidity of the breath? or the spacing between sugar cristals? or something else?

Answer (score 4):

By breathing on a lump of sugar, you are condensing the water vapor in the air on the sugar itself; water molecules tend to solvate saccarose and thus they reduce the energy of the interaction between saccarose molecules, making the crystal a lesser bound system, more easily broken with bare hands!